# Place picker disabled but implementation guide still published

Tags: ios, swift, gmsplacepicker

I was about to follow instructions on this page https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/placepicker related to place picker then I saw the deprecate notice.

Are instructions in that page is up to date ?  Does that use the new SDK ?
I mean, all instructions seem to target existing users of the APIs. But what about new users who want to implement such feature ?

I was assuming that if the code is not valid (since 2 days), it wouldn't be published anymore.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

its strange, because i have implemented it in android application on store 7 months ago.and places picker still working normally.